# Rancid configuration for remote access to devices in UBUNTU Server 13.04

Tags: bash, shell

How do I configure rancid and clogin file in ubuntu?
I have already installed and configured rancid along with clogin file. But when I try to use clogin for getting remote access to my networking devices I get this error.

```
Jumpbox:~$ clogin oes1234
No command 'clogin' found, did you mean:
 Command 'slogin' from package 'openssh-client' (main)
 Command 'rlogin' from package 'krb5-clients' (universe)
 Command 'rlogin' from package 'rsh-redone-client' (universe)
 Command 'rlogin' from package 'rsh-client' (universe)
 Command 'qlogin' from package 'gridengine-client' (universe)
 Command 'login' from package 'login' (main)
 Command 'llogin' from package 'latd' (universe)
clogin: command not found
```

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. You should ask this on either [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com) or [su], either of which is more appropriate. Voting to migrate there instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When installing rancid, clogin was placed in `/usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin`, which wasn't in my path.  It still runs from the command line just fine, though.

I had to create my own ~/.cloginrc file, and `chmod 700 ~/.cloginrc` before it would let me run the command.

This was on Ubuntu 12.04.

A basic run-through, I installed it via `apt-get install rancid`.  Then I had to add these lines to my (non-existent) ~/cloginrc:

```
add user 192.168.11.1 admin
add password 192.168.11.1 MyPassword
```

Then at the command line, I typed:

```
/usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin 192.168.11.1
```

It performed the login process for me, based on the IP address.

That's pretty much it, though I might point out you could even leave your `.cloginrc` empty and just type `/usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin -u admin -p MyPassword 192.168.11.1` instead.

Here is a sample `~/.cloginrc` from their GitHub:

https://github.com/dotwaffle/rancid-git/blob/master/cloginrc.sample

Comment: Can someone give me detailed steps of rancid installation and configuration alongwith .cloginrc file..